# Ruby - Strip all HTML tags from string with Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, format, gsub

I have the following string as an example

```
"<p>Hello,</p><p><br></p><p>my name is Same</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Farewell,</p><p>Same</p>"
```

And I would like to strip all HTML tags from it. I was using the following method which kind of worked

```
Nokogiri::HTML(CGI.unescapeHTML(@message_preview)).content
```

But it ultimately produced,

```
"Hello,my name is SameFarewell,Same"
```

When I wanted

```
"Hello, my name is Same Farewell, Same"
```

Notice the spaces, given a line break, I want there to be a space in its place instead of being the very next character in the string.

I was hoping to try to use gsub or regex but am kind of lost on how to make it happen.

Comment: I guess the easiest solution might be to replace all line break `<br>` with a space before your remove the HTML tags!? Also to trim multiple spaces to a single one (in case of multiple line breaks).

Comment: Actually, yea. You are right. I ended up using `@message_preview.gsub!(/<br>/, ' ')` But i just realized I need to account for a whole host of html tags because of the keyboard options. Bold, italic, underline, ol, ul, quotes etc. So I need to find a way to include all that in my gsub and then run the nokogiri

Comment: @xander you guess wrong; with this approach, sooner or later you’ll find yourself implementing HTML parser on regular expressions.

Comment: you are going about it the right way using a parser like `nokogiri` doing this as a Regex is a bad idea

Comment: Why is that? What are the downsides to regex over nokogiri?

Comment: This is Rails? Don't reinvent the wheel! Use the `sanitize` helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` here passing a regex which works for your example (s is your string).

```
def wordy s
  s.split(/\<.*?\>/)
   .map(&:strip)
   .reject(&:empty?)
   .join(' ')
   .gsub(/\s,/,',')
end

s = "<p>Hello,</p><p><br></p><p>my name is Same</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Farewell,</p><p>Same</p>"
t = "<p>Hello <strong>Jim</strong>,</p><p> </p><p>This is <em>Charlie</em> and<u> I wanted to say</u></p><ol><li>hello</li><li>goodby</li></ol><p> </p><p>Farewell,</p><p>Lawrence</p>"

p wordy s
#"Hello, my name is Same Farewell, Same"

p wordy t
#"Hello Jim, This is Charlie and I wanted to say hello goodby Farewell, Lawrence"
```

Comment: Hey this could work! I was using split before this issue. I just notice though that I now need to account for a lot of other text options. `<ol>, <ul>, bold, italics, underline, quotes` etc. Is it possible to include those in this regex example you provided? If so, mind ammending it for me, this stuff is very confusing to me!

Comment: I take it back, it kind of works. I have this new example string with what I discussed, `"<p>Hello <strong>Jim</strong>,</p><p> </p><p>This is <em>Charlie</em> and<u> I wanted to say</u></p><ol><li>hello</li><li>goodby</li></ol><p> </p><p>Farewell,</p><p>Lawrence</p>"`

And using your method, I get this
`"Hello  Jim ,   This is  Charlie  and  I wanted to say hello goodby   Farewell, Lawrence"`. 

How can I strip those extra spaces? Maybe do a check to make sure there is only a max of 1 space and no consecutive spaces?

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much Sagar!

Comment: @vin_Bin87 refactored answer again. I do agree with others that you should use a dedicated library rather than regex. These libraries are tried and tested whereas regex can break and not work for fringe examples.

Comment: Hey, it's actually including this `&nbsp;` in the resulted output...`"Hello&nbsp; Jim, This is&nbsp; Daniel .` Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @vin_Bin87 no idea :(

Comment: Don't use a home-made scrubber. Either use Rails' `sanitize` or something like `loofah`.

Comment: FYI: It misses <!-- comments in HTML

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#traverse`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#traverse-instance_method) does not return an enumerator when no block is given, that’s why we need this ugly hack with defining a local variable upfront.

```
require 'nokogiri'

result, input = [], "<p>Hello,</p><p><br></p><p>my name is Same</p>" \
                    "<p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Farewell,</p><p>Same</p>"
Nokogiri::HTML(CGI.unescapeHTML(input)).traverse do |e|
  result << e.text if e.text?
end
result.join(' ')
#⇒ "Hello, my name is Same Farewell, Same"
```

Answer (score 0):

My decision:

```
description.gsub!(/<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/, ' ').strip
```